# What does the Keyword tag mean in a *.vcxproj file?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I see the following in many *.vcxproj files

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  <ProjectGuid>{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}</ProjectGuid>
  <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
  <RootNamespace>yadayada</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

What does the `<Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>` segment mean? Does it affect any behavior during the build?

In general, where can I find documentation on the tags in a project file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>` tells Visual Studio which of the Windows-specific dependencies you are going to use.

It depends on type of the project selected during its creation.
[image]

For already present project you may view this setting in the Project Properties --> General.
[image]

Now, up to your question.

> Does it affect any behavior during the build?

`Win32Proj` means that `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` will contain paths to WinAPI libraries. If it were `MFCProj`, then paths to MFC headers would have been present there **in addition** to WinAPI. For instance, see [in this project file](https://github.com/4sily/VisualStudioLinkerIssue/blob/master/A_SDK/A_SDK_2017.vcxproj#L12)

As for the documentation, try to check [this article from MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure/), it explains the meaning of some of the tags. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/working-with-project-properties) are the guidelines for working with project properties.
Note that those properties are supposed to be viewed and edited from the UI, so a structure of a real *.vcxproj file may not seem to you extremely friendly or human-readable.